# Basic Question on Black Holes and the Potential Loss of Conservation of Energy/Mass

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, energy-conservation, mass-energy

I am reading Kip Thorne's "Black Holes and Time Warps" and I have a basic question on a topic he is discussing while talking about Einstein and Eddington's disbelief in black holes.

So the general gist is this: a mass falls into a black hole and its mass and energy  are not conserved (ie. lost to the universe).  My question, is: isn't matter and energy actually conserved when an object falls into a black hole?  A objects mass is definitely conserved as it would be added to the singularity's mass.  It might be small comparatively, but where else would it go?  The energy portion of an object (or energy trapped) would be conserved as well.  It might be changed to another form inside the black hole at the point of the singularity but again it's not like it will drip out somewhere)...

(I ask your pardon if I didn't phrase my question correctly as I am not a scientist)...

I do not understand the argument about a BH's not conserving mass / energy.  Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Hi Rick, the title of your question refers to data, (information loss) but you don't expand on this in your post, so to me at least, it's not clear what you are asking. Do you mean the loss of information contained within the mass? Something along the lines of  this answer?  https://www.quora.com/Why-is-having-information-lost-in-black-holes-a-problem

Comment: Changed the title- 80 hours this week at work...  my thoughts did not translate very well :-}

Comment: Have a read of this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/465446/ and see if it helps. Conservation of energy (I would call it all energy) only acts locally, it does not apply to the universe on large scales.